# configurar variables de memoria para Oracle 11 y 12 linux

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle-11g, opensuse

actualmente estoy intentando instalar una base de datos Oracle (11g o 12c) sobre un opensuse virtualizado, dentro de las guias que seguí solicitan modificar las variables de memoria en el archivo `/etc/sysctl.conf` las variables son `kernel.shmmax kernel.shmmin` y `kernel.shmall`, la guia sugiere colocar los valores

```
kernel.shmall = 2097152
kernel.shmmax = 536870912
kernel.shmmni = 4096
```

Sin embargo al parecer estos valores dependen de la memoria física de la máquina (en mi caso 4GB para la virtual) ya que al ejecutar con los valores de la guia al crear la base de datos Oracle presenta error.

De acuerdo a los 4GB de memoria física que tiene la virtual, cuales serian los valores optimos para estas variables??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo esta guia https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LADBI/app_manual.htm#LADBI7866

Visualiza el contenido de estos tres ficheros y verás la configuración actual. /proc/sys/kernel/shmmni /proc/sys/kernel/shmall o /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax

Luego es cuestión de hacer cuentas en bytes segun el porcentaje.

**shmall**

40 percent of the size of physical memory in pages
Note: If the server supports multiple databases, or uses a large SGA, then set this parameter to a value that is equal to the total amount of shared memory, in 4K pages, that the system can use at one time.

/proc/sys/kernel/shmall

**shmmax**
Half the size of physical memory in bytes
See My Oracle Support Note 567506.1 for additional information about configuring shmmax.

/proc/sys/kernel/shmmax

**shmmni**
4096    /proc/sys/kernel/shmmni

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya había pasado por esta pagina pero no me detuve a la lectura.